# Rails is Using HTML View When Requesting Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Weird issue where I'm asking for the JS file, but Rails is serving the HTML file. And it's only on my staging server (Heroku) and not on my local machine.

I have a dynamic Javascript file which is something that needs to be included in other pages via a script to like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/embed.js></script>
```

That embed maps to a controller and action which also handles HTML. The relevant route looks like this:

```
match "/embed(.:format)" => "articles#embed", as: "embed"
```

And the controller action is pretty standard.

```
def embed
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      #it renders some HTML
    end
    format.js #no block is given
  end
end
```

And, I have two views under app/views/articles

- embed.html.haml
- embed.js.coffee

On my local machine, requesting localhost:3000/embed.js works. It renders the Javascript without a problem. However, on my staging server, here's what I see in the logs:

```
Started GET "/embed.js" for 124.168.219.36 at 2012-11-04 00:23:01 +0000
Processing by ArticlesController#embed as JS
  Rendered articles/embed.html.haml (1.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
```

The Internal Server Error is not the issue. The issue is that it recognises the request as JS, yet decides to render the HTML template and *only* on staging.

What's going on?

Comment: I don't think this will solve the problem, but try using `format.json` instead of `format.js`. If nothing else works, you can make a new route (really, try everything before doing that) and force this route to use js, like `match "/embed(.:format)" => "articles#embed", as: "embed", :format => "js"`

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. While I can't figure the discrepancy between development and production, it appears the browsers request javascript as text/html and Rails seems to favour their requested type over the explicit format. In the controller, if I do `format.js { render action: "embed.js.coffee", content_type: "text/javascript" }` that seems to fix the problem on staging.

Comment: Except actually, now, the Coffeescript isn't getting compiled to Javascript so it's pretty useless. Will keep working on it…